# Sudden shutdown with IllegalStateException without doing anything

Tags: java, android

After 26 minutes leaving my app running without doing anything with it as a user, "app has stopped" window suddenly pop up and Logcat prints only this:

```
07-15 20:34:16.595 27361-27363/test.game D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 1419K, 44% free 13902K/24391K, paused 4ms+9ms, total 66ms
07-15 20:34:28.997 27361-27363/test.game D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 1416K, 43% free 13903K/24391K, paused 3ms+7ms, total 56ms
07-15 20:34:29.418 27361-27361/test.game D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-15 20:34:29.418 27361-27361/test.game W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412b52a0)
07-15 20:34:29.498 27361-27361/test.game E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension()
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15293)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2397)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1974)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1217)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1390)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4481)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas where could be problem? It happened now for 2nd time (1st time it happened slightly sooner, in about ~13 mins), so it's not some "random" issue.

I can't provide any sample code since none of the Logcat errors links to my code (all goes to the source of specific View). Another strange behaviour is, this happened twice on my S3 Mini (in mentioned 13 and 26 mins), but didn't happened yet on my old Ace S5830i - app is running 4 hours 9 minutes and still nothing here!

---

edit n1:

Only thing which is running on background is Timer executed each 17ms. I'm displaying hours, minutes, seconds and milis on screen thanks to it.

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()  ...

    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

    milisecond = currentTime % 1000;
    long x = currentTime / 1000;
    second = x % 60;
    x /= 60;
    minute = x % 60;
    x /= 60;
    hour = x % 24;
```

variable start is another System.currentTimeMillis(). It has still value, assigned when this Timer was created.

It's also possible that S3 Mini was a bit "overworked", because I've been developing and testing on it from computer all the day (and the newest Android Studio eats quite a lot memory in phone against AS v1.0.0). I'll try another tests tomorow and let you know how it ended.

Comment: Is this the complete log? Is there a "Caused by" line in the log? It might be a hardware specific issue - something to do with RAM management perhaps. But given the log above, we can't say much.

Comment: That's all what I've found in logcat. No "caused by", no "blue links" to code - only grays to source code of views. Quite a bad situation. Added some info in main post.